# How to remove the time box?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs, cv

## Definition of EducationEntry

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class
            
\usepackage{hyperref}                        
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
\noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
\colorbox{Black}{%
\parbox{6em}{%
\hfill\color{White}#2}} \par  % Duration
\noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
\normalsize \par}
\begin{document}
\EducationEntry{IUS NATURA CAL LTDA}{}{Estágiario 23/06/2014 á 31/10/2014\\Programador Junior 03/11/2014 á 29/07/2016\\Analista de Sistemas 01/08/2016 até o momento}
{Análise e desenvolvimento de melhorias e correção de problemas no SISTEMA CAL®. Rotina de trabalho totalmente adaptada à metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil (Scrum) integrado ao controle de versão TFS. Modelagem e estruturação de tabelas.}
\end{document}
```

*How can I remove what was highlighted in the image?*

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Where is the definition of `\EducationEntry`? Can you please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question. Without your question is somehow unclear. Such a MWE should start with `\documentclass`, include all packages and preamble definitions, that are needed to reproduce the problem (but only those!), and a document body from `\begin{document}` down to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Edited @Schweinebacke.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I'm sorry, I hope this is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example there are several issues, e.g.:

- You should not use `utf8x` unless you really need it, because the usage could result in problems with other packages.
- You should load `hyperref` as late as possible.
- You don't need to load `url` after `hyperref`, because `hyperref` already loads `url`.
- It is somehow strange to load `babel` with option `english` only, but use another language (not English, maybe Portugese?).
- It makes no sense to change the text area and margins loading `geometry` and then change `\textheight` using `\setlength`. It makes more sense to use `geometry` to change the height of the text area.
- Setting a whole paragraph in `\small` but switching back to `\normalsize` before `\par` so that several font parameters of `\normalsize` will be used, i.e., `\baselineskip` of `\normalsize`. Mostly using `\par` before switching back to `\normalsize` is recommended.
- A page break could occur after the *heading* "IUS NATURA CAL LTDA" and inside the italic block. I think, this is not wanted.
- `\EducationEntry` seems to be used to format a kind of block, but there is no initial `\par` to ensure that it always start a new paragraph.

So I would suggest something like:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[english,main=portuges]{babel}% hope that's correct, I don't know the language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Don't use utf8x if you don't need it!
\usepackage[textheight=700px]{geometry}% saving trees but uglyfy documents
\usepackage{hyperref}% load hyperref as late as possible

\setkomafont{minisec}{\rmfamily}

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[3]{%
  \minisec{#1}
  \textit{#2}\par\nobreak        % School
  \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #3\par % Description
  \normalsize
}
\begin{document}
\EducationEntry{IUS NATURA CAL LTDA}{Estágiario 23/06/2014 á 31/10/2014\\*Programador Junior 03/11/2014 á 29/07/2016\\*Analista de Sistemas 01/08/2016 até o momento}
{Análise e desenvolvimento de melhorias e correção de problemas no SISTEMA CAL®. Rotina de trabalho totalmente adaptada à metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil (Scrum) integrado ao controle de versão TFS. Modelagem e estruturação de tabelas.}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[english,main=portuges]{babel}% hope that's correct
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Don't use utf8x if you don't need it!
\usepackage[textheight=700px]{geometry}% saving trees but uglyfy documents
\usepackage{hyperref}% load hyperref as late as possible

\setkomafont{minisec}{\rmfamily}

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[3]{%
  \minisec{#1}
  \textit{#2}\par\nobreak        % School
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{0pt}
  \small #3% Description
  \end{addmargin}
}
\begin{document}
\EducationEntry{IUS NATURA CAL LTDA}{Estágiario 23/06/2014 á 31/10/2014\\*Programador Junior 03/11/2014 á 29/07/2016\\*Analista de Sistemas 01/08/2016 até o momento}
{Análise e desenvolvimento de melhorias e correção de problemas no SISTEMA CAL®. Rotina de trabalho totalmente adaptada à metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil (Scrum) integrado ao controle de versão TFS. Modelagem e estruturação de tabelas.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, I've removed all packages not needed and not commented in the list at the beginning of this answer. I also removed one argument of `\EducationEntry`, because normally it makes not sense to have a command with four arguments and use only three. But if you prefer to have a command with four arguments, that does not use the second one, you can use:

```
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{%
  \minisec{#1}
  \textit{#3}\par\nobreak        % School
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{0pt}
  \small #4% Description
  \end{addmargin}
}
```

Comment: I was adventurous in the latex world out of curiosity, I'm going to take all the questions into consideration. Thank you very much, I did not know that a simple curriculum would give so much work. :)

Comment: @cura: Copying code from somewhere without understanding it, gives often extra work. So please read the description of `\minisec` and `addmargin` in the KOMA-Script manual. And read the description of, e.g., `\colorbox` in the `xcolor` manual. Reading a good introduction into LaTeX often also helps. But `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` are low level TeX. I did not know any LaTeX introduction that describes them. Every beginning is hard. Depending on your demands it will become harder or easier after some dozens of LaTeX documents. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Remove/comment out the `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
%        \colorbox{black}{%
%            \parbox{6em}{%
%            \hfill\color{white}#2}}
        \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}
\begin{document}
\EducationEntry{IUS NATURA CAL LTDA}{}{Estágiario 23/06/2014 á 31/10/2014\\Programador Junior 03/11/2014 á 29/07/2016\\Analista de Sistemas 01/08/2016 até o momento}
{Análise e desenvolvimento de melhorias e correção de problemas no SISTEMA CAL®. Rotina de trabalho totalmente adaptada à metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil (Scrum) integrado ao controle de versão TFS. Modelagem e estruturação de tabelas.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make the background of the colorbox white, instead of black.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
    \colorbox{White}{%
        \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par  % Duration
    \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}


\begin{document}
    \EducationEntry{IUS NATURA CAL LTDA}{}{Estágiario 23/06/2014 á 31/10/2014\\Programador Junior 03/11/2014 á 29/07/2016\\Analista de Sistemas 01/08/2016 até o momento}
    {Análise e desenvolvimento de melhorias e correção de problemas no SISTEMA CAL®. Rotina de trabalho totalmente adaptada à metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil (Scrum) integrado ao controle de versão TFS. Modelagem e estruturação de tabelas.}
\end{document}
```